# MacOs Rejection for non-public api

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store-connect

I got my app rejected due to a `non-public api` call.

> framework: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation'
>   : _NSErrorWithFilePath 
>   : _NSErrorWithFilePathAndErrno

I did a `grep` on the project folder to locate those methods, as I found on another `StackOverflow` question, but `grep` did not provide anything.

```
    grep -R '_NSErrorWithFilePath' *
    grep -R '_NSErrorWithFilePathAndErrno' *
```

How can I find where those methods are located??

**Edit:**
I tried to export the .app file and while grepping on it I find something

```
Binary file myAppName.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib matches
```

What's the best way to proceed to solve this?

**Solved** 
Got this answer from the App Review Board:

> Thank you for contacting the App Review Board.
>
> App Review Board has completed their review of your appeal for your
>   app *** and determined that this version of your app is not in
>   violation of Guideline 2.5.1.
>
> We will place the app back in review process shortly.
>
> Thank you for your commitment to Mac app development.
>
> Shin Y. App Review Board

So apparently it's a problem on their side, now my app is stuck **"In Review"** since this morning, I keep you posted.

Comment: Got any third party frameworks ?

Comment: @WarrenBurton yep I do, but shouldn't I see the match on the related framework? The result of the second grep looks like it's something generated by Xcode, am I wrong? (I mean `libswiftFoundation.dylib`) Since I do not see while inspecting the source code in the first grep

Comment: You won't necessarily see who is using those methods. You can see them in Foundation because they are exposed for use ( by Apple only ) but if any of your 3rd party libraries are just static libraries and using those methods you won't be able to see that. In that case only way forward is to start grepping the `otool -ov` output on the libraries for a hunch.

Comment: I was also rejected for `_NSErrorWithFilePath` and `_NSErrorWithFilePathAndErrno` 8 hours ago. This was a small patch with only minor source code changes. I'm fairly sure that this is a new test by the app review team --  not that that helps.

Comment: Exactly the same with me. I'm quite sure that I'm not using any non public functions. The difference with the previous version is only small bug fixes. So this is a new test indeed. Still nobody knows why this reject has been triggered.

Comment: I appealed to review the decision, I'll get you updated if I receive any answer

Comment: Edited the post with the answer I got from the App Review Board

Answer (score 0):

My app was rejected for the same reason ~1h ago.

One of my apps was rejected a couple of weeks ago for the same reason but another framework. Back then it was a false alarm and I am 100% certain that is now.

I am asking Apple to check my app again.

Keep in mind that you do not have to use the private api in order to get the rejection. It is enough if the signature is the roughly same.

My app was rejected because it said that I was using the "CFHashByte" constructor which has the following signature:

CFHashBytes(uint8_t *bytes, CFIndex length)

My app had a function called "getBytes(UInt8 bytes, index: Int, length: Int)". The signature was similiar, especially the naming and the types. So maybe that's why the auto check detected this private API call.

So maybe check your app for a similiar signature. Otherwise, just write a message to Apple in iTunes Connect section where you received your error report.

TL;DR: Check your app for functions with similiar signatures.

Regards,
Sascha

Comment: Any response yet?

Comment: Yes, the app just passed the review process, same binary.

Answer (score 0):

I just received the following note from Apple's Technical Support:

*Thanks for contacting Developer Technical Support. We worked with the App Review team to identify and resolve the unexpected private API issue.*

*If your app is currently in the Rejected state, please respond to the App Review team in Resolution Center and they will continue the review process.*

*Alternatively, you may choose to upload a new version of your app.*

*While you were initially charged a technical support incident for this request, we have assigned a replacement incident back to your Apple Developer Program account.*

Let's hope it passes.

Comment: So it looks like a problem on their side, good to know. As soon as I receive an answer I'll share it :)